# Passing selected Image in cell image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

My application consists of 2 tap bars.
First tap is TableView and second - VC.
When I'm on first VC, I selected picture and press the button, which should transfer the selected picture on cell image.

I'm trying to save image in UserDefaults but then it turns out that all lines are with the same picture

[image: screen]

In my VC, I save TextField by this method:

```
func saveButton() { 
let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

var items:[String]

if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

    items = tempItems

    items.append(nameTextField.text!)

} else {

    items = [nameTextField.text!]
}
UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    nameTextField.text = ""
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

And choose the image

Then I tap "Save" button

In my Table view:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //     Load Item Func
        let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

        if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

            items = tempItems
        }
        table.reloadData()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellPrototype

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.pointNameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
         return cell
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the selected image to next ViewController?

Comment: Or do you want to pass the selected image to second tab?

Comment: No, my goal is to pass selected image from one VC to cell image.

Comment: if you made this project then can you just share your screenshot whatever you did?

Comment: @Bogdan You say that you want to pass image from **ViewController** to **TableviewCell**?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani yes

Comment: @Bogdan You just need to reload table view in ViewWillAppear method if you store captured image in anywhere otherwise you can also send by delegate method.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani can you send me an example, how i can do it?

Comment: @Bogdan First of all tell me from where you fetch tableview data? and what exactly happen in detail View

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani add a code in description

Answer (score 1):

You can pass image by creating a variable in **Second VC** like this

**UITableView Delegate Method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCell

    if let DetailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController{

        DetailVC.Selected_image = cell.YourImageView.image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailVC,animated: true)
    }

}
```

**Create Variable in Second VC**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var Selected_image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(Selected_image)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image from cell to detailViewController here is partail pseudo Code

```
tableView (cell , didSelectCellAtIndexPath) {
 if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
   let image = cell.image 
   let detailVC = DetailViewController(..) // instantiate from storyboard
    detailVC.selectedImage = image 
    navigationViewController.push(detailVC)
}
}

Class DetailVC: UIViewController {
 var selectedImage: UIImage!

 // can access image anywhere in this class after passing  
}
```